# Implementing Type Level Depth First Search in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to implement a depth first search (DFS) algorithm using a type function in TypeScript.

Here are my codes:
First I defined all the different type functions that are needed for the eventual `DFSRecursive` type function where I implement the recursive DFS algorithm.

```
const MyGraph: Graph = {
  A: ["B", "C", "D"],
  B: ["F", "E"],
  C: ["E", "F"],
  D: ["E", "F", "G"],
  E: [],
  F: [],
  G: [],
};

type Graph = {
  A: ["B", "C", "D"],
  B: ["F", "E"],
  C: ["E", "F"],
  D: ["E", "F", "G"],
  E: [],
  F: [],
  G: [],
}

export type Concat<T extends string[], U extends string[]> = [...T, ...U];
export type Pop<T extends string[]> = T extends [...infer Rest extends string[], infer Last extends string]
  ? T extends [infer Last]
  ? []
  : Rest
  : never;
export type Append<T extends string[], U extends string> = [...T, U];
export type IsEmpty<T extends string[]> = T extends [] ? true : false;
export type Difference<T extends string[], U extends string[], Result extends string[] = []> =
  T extends [infer First extends string, ...infer Rest extends string[]]
  ? false extends Contains<U, First> 
  ? Difference<Rest, U, Append<Result, First>>
  : Difference<Rest, U, Result>
  : T extends string[]
  ? string[]
  : Result;
export type Peek<T extends string[]> = T extends [...infer Rest extends string[], infer Last extends string]
  ? Last
  : T extends [infer Last extends string]
  ? Last
  : T extends string[]
  ? never
  : never;
export type Contains<T extends string[], Element extends string> = T extends [infer Head, ...infer Rest extends string[]]
  ? Head extends Element
  ? true
  : Contains<Rest, Element>
  : false;

export type DFSRecursive<Curr extends string, GraphType extends Graph, Stack extends string[], Visited extends string[] = []> =
  true extends IsEmpty<Stack>
  ? Visited
  : true extends Contains<Visited, Peek<Stack>>
  ? DFSRecursive<Peek<Stack>, GraphType, Pop<Stack>, Visited> //Append<Visited, Peek<Stack>>>
  : GraphType[keyof Graph & Peek<Stack>] extends infer GT extends string[]
  ? Difference<GT, Visited> extends infer D extends string[]
  ? Peek<Stack> extends infer PS extends string
  ? Append<Visited, PS> extends infer A extends string[]
  ? Concat<Pop<Stack>, D> extends infer C extends string[]
  ? DFSRecursive<Peek<Stack>, GraphType, C, A>
  : never
  : never
  : never
  : never
  : never;

type X = DFSRecursive<"A", Graph, ["A"]>
```

After a few hours of work, I realise there an error:

```
Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

How can I possibly resolve this?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTwOICcCGAHAFgLhqzLGAXhgG8AoGGAQTwG0AiAIUYBoZGBhdzgEUYBdNlRjMGjAGK9GAUSEjqXCfI5SFovipnS1SDdVkNhoyccX5zFAL4BuChSgIMAU3zpsJcqLowmrNR41ARNqcT91NXlQmGUI1U5pGK14nRl9GKM-GLNsiyQrawcXAA8MEBRYJ1dY8GA0KAAeABUYUqgXMAATCBhoFABLMABzemEYAFU2ko7u3v6h0cEAPi96ADpN5o5N9YnBe1LyyphqtwAFEAwW6dmevqhBkbHV0lb2zvuNzaGAMxcUDAAEouaC3T7zR6LMYcP4AmAAGTQYI%20cweT2GglEAH4YO8ZhC-HDAUjoFjqLixqI8CDoNSYGAXAA3AGHMoVKrONw0DCubo3VH3BbPcZTQWQjGvPy7baTA4UI4c05cmAASQgsgAthgnAKCWjhUspfi7r0xjBcY8AK5uPC-NAAGwgLjZx05NT4A1%20-xQnWALj1pvR0NF4INUJFHFpVodsHFwZFaxWJFEJsJ9GJMEkAxQKP1Qojwx2PzAPuBoLj%20YlIfJFpg9qdbnjXHAUDQQwgjQmHGzuagqxxME93oBfoDtKgHG7tF5n0a0djPZz0GWy3pw59Y-nFanUdBMf79LT4YxVIpCaW9IXUFdSrOMHOLhcAGtA4TDS8vMevrtMxOwwWp7jJmpKVkGhq1rioFHgBZogciYHvoWkGIghMHxh%20KGMiyKD0thrIKuyJz3i2YBth2b4niGHCyA6Liap0iFUSMxqwUSpbwgAEi4aBdMW6x-hWbGYSh3G8WxtH0Yxg7Wi49KkeRkDbtANF0QxZFrtQdqOs69iEW6yoepIADKILAFauYDCyjRcBZgIYYWHAENgzQqvGzlYBwxltsAz7CYWMIwAAagMEADB0XT%20UBSavKIslseqWo6ggjTeWgvmaXWIVhRF9Lxc2rbtkp2XhS4fEPk%20r5pRlmW4nwJlmRZYXWY%20L6pT5z7LE5HhYK5rgcJc1zVZ1HAlRFqwAPQTTyfJdI0Y1lQNlXtelnWrvSHl9S49DPi4CAgL87iEDAABkFVtcNyyCGxmZIN%201YioOG6jmA-qNHdo2haVXSrPGmZ8FFIaDq1VUdb9VYwJm5zGYDIyDjNc4LeV0Pg0GmY0LDl7nqR9RNINK0ZRwfCo4SmZcJjZ51vVpkuOZlktctl3dYQW0cFwHA0JleD4bhWkMsyAJ4QLvMwNzwtCzhen3gAGl41ONfTAaMDQvAeRwTAqysDhTTAXQuId1MAEwABSbVyeBm-1sR2Xg-SfTlZV4AioVQPQ-TXaQABy4AuF5HVOy7buPB7MDe4yACUMAALSrM70BByggg4BQOvUNQXrBV9EWQ70YcuMnqdp0XSNJinE1F5Dh3DTnoc%20wX5cV2n1ekFSZcVxntkoICYAgLAQyZw7XT143adI%20smCzcbncoOH2sNyPvwVKHLgDMMWAAEYgBZkNgEdLlcvQ09J23I-t4dnsr2vm-bz3fe70jw%20n6fw3j7O3TGxfq8b1vM9z2fDK9xgMNR%20I9fRQAsvfLOZU-5FwvjMb2esvAv3KBgY2s9C7UDARAocJkTaW19sveBIA9b22%20n7Va4cgA)

Comment: That's quite a lot of code; could you possibly reduce it to a [mre]?  For instance, just on first glance, your `Concat` and `Append` types seem like a level of indirection you don't need since they're just synonyms for basic variadic tuple operations.  I don't know if we'll be able to figure it out if you *do* reduce it, but it's more likely.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: If I were trying to implement a type-level depth-first search, first it would need to be searching a graph of nested tuple types (since otherwise there's no key ordering and you end up searching all keys at once, which is the ultimate breadth-first search), and then I would do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3VK2N), which seems to work (it prefers paths like `X[0][0][0][0]` over `X[1]`).  But who knows if this is what you're looking for ‍♂️

Comment: Hi @jcalz, what you have shared is very valuable to me. Would you mind elaborating on your point of how representing the graph with an adjacency list would make the algorithm search through all the keys at once? I didn't get that.

Comment: You can use mapped types or distributive conditional types to operate on individual members of the union of keys of an object type, but they perform the same operation on *every* member and you cannot abort it.  There's no straightforward way to say "iterate the properties of `T` *in order* and halt when you find one that satisfies a given condition".  At best you can grab all the members that satisfy that condition.  If you are willing to dictate the order of the keys, it will work, but then that's isomorphic to a tuple type, so you might as well use those.

Comment: @jcalz, Thanks for taking the time to write your brilliant exposition. That really clears up stuff. Agree with you that operations on distributive conditional types act on all types in the union. My follow up question is, is that an artefact of functional programming? Because early aborting of said operation would be a side effect. And like you'd said, changing the input to the pure function would have the desired early-aborting outcome without any side effect. Am I grossly mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with clever meta-programming like this is that it's usually easier to write the code than to read it and understand what's going on.

I can't point out your error exactly. I think there is probably an error in `Difference()`, which doesn't seem to behave as intended, but maybe there are multiple problems, because your code is rather convoluted, and it doesn't seem like you've tested any of the helper functions that your DFS implementation relies on.

However, I can rewrite the algorithm in a simpler way that works:

```
export type Contains<A extends string[], E extends string> =
  A extends [infer Head extends string, ...infer Rest extends string[]]
  ? Head extends E ? true : Contains<Rest, E> : false;

export type Minus<A extends string[], B extends string[]> =
   A extends [infer First extends string, ...infer Rest extends string[]]
   ? (true extends Contains<B, First> ? Minus<Rest, B> : [First, ...Minus<Rest, B>])
   : [];

export type DFSRecursiveImpl<
    GraphType extends Record<string, string[]>,
    Stack extends string[],
    Visited extends string[]> =
  Stack extends [...infer Prefix extends string[], infer V extends string]
  ? Minus<GraphType[V], Visited> extends [infer W extends string, ...string[]]
  ? DFSRecursiveImpl<GraphType, [...Stack, W], [...Visited, W]>
  : DFSRecursiveImpl<GraphType, Prefix, Visited>
  : Visited;

export type DFSRecursive<GraphType extends Record<string, string[]>, Start extends string> =
  DFSRecursiveImpl<GraphType, [Start], [Start]>;
```

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#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-w5-cLxmhfEZv2fXh-z5BQ0BfcCPxAgCFHhGDQJAj8yQgrxeDBBC4BGbDIPJfDZAAX3yK8+mkBFkSrXcJ2dD9SGfCQcgUAB6VjFBaC5kh4NAeHhHgyTgWR2N6AA9bxZHI1pKO3atxwbD832YtiOPOXDkhEjiFAkqSGTQW85NoxSfy-FS4FEvi+AuLTxMk8j4UM6jRzjYA6JpD8-3M0SBOsjTyVsnT7IZfhZOcndXPc6kP3A7yON4QK4F08iRic6MIprKK4KYliLI4kZEuShkhLC9L5Lckzn3QuKAtEoKyIZAAtNKaMiyrGpy1S4Ga7YaDCAAjPAICqbxgTqpLJPyHyBqGqob2pHB6BwTAKBoFhUFIABaCR1P6sJ4FaaU4EwCB4BwOAwCgCAUFgRA4AgDQERm4bCAbCw9OHZ65snalbzvJ81Fff9iMvBl4S+whEjCDJ4FK1rMv+l83w4YiGM6vLOL+QrJoHYoHPC8qkRwLQSV6K1tCoE11wXUkD2nBVVFnKA2QlCnQHbNmQB5AiFBPRlWdgUAJC8OGXMyummxPZiGrhUhUVRYAwDlFqxZxImSaFYBEAe8kfsEvWf0YmryFaVL+AMxyyWxqaOIcAArZllf65kcCqVBnw6i16BO+AaFbTBiwtFa3o+1B7cd4sAEYVYytXibczXtcekz2pym2mQd1EnZdt2nsGl6bxZY54jgZag6xTI8ACNbUBgCA4DCWh-cDnFBZNZp3vI8Os+LAAmGPCfj4hE518H8+++i89m16DefI28iAA)

The above code is generic in that it accepts any type that maps strings to string-arrays as a graph definition, but it doesn't check that the vertex strings actually exist as property keys.

More or less by accident, it still works if some keys are not defined, and treats missing vertices simply (e.g., `{"A":["B"]}` is treated like `{"A":["B"], "B":[]}`) which is pretty good default behavior.

It's possible to create a safer version that requires vertices to correspond with keys in the graph type, for example, like this:

```
export type DFSRecursiveSafe<
    Vertex extends string,
    GraphType extends Record<Vertex, Vertex[]>,
    Start extends Vertex>
  = DFSRecursive<GraphType, Start>;

type Accepted = DFSRecursiveSafe<keyof Graph, Graph, "A">;  // A B F E C D G
```

This guarantees that the graph type only contains edges between known vertices (see the playground link for more examples).

Final note: in the code I've used `string` everywhere, but it's equally possibly to use `PropertyKey` instead, which has the advantage that you could use numbers or symbols as vertex ids.

---

I also saw a comment asking how I arrived at this solution. Like in the original question, I started with a minimal Python function:

```
graph = {
  'A': ["B", "C", "D"],
  'B': ["F", "E"],
  'C': ["E", "F"],
  'D': ["E", "F", "G"],
  'E': [],
  'F': [],
  'G': [],
}

def DfsRecursive(stack, visited):
  if not stack:
    return visited
  v = stack[-1]
  for w in graph[v]:
    if w not in visited:
      return DfsRecursive(stack + [w], visited + [w])
  return DfsRecursive(stack[:-1], visited)

print(DfsRecursive(['A'], ['A']))
```

It should not be too hard to see how this maps to the TypeScript definitions (the for- and if- statements are combined into the Minus<> instantation).

Comment: Please note that you can use twoslash queries `// ^?` to show types in playground, e.g https://tsplay.dev/mpQzXW